# Display new lines (not new line characters) when using diffObj in R?

Tags: r, stringr

```
install.packages("diffobj")
library(diffobj)


first_string <- "It's
a
nice
day"

second_string <- "it's
a
nice
day"
```

produces

[image]

How would we produce the same output *but with actual new lines displayed on screen* (rather than `\n`)

Note: `diffObj()` has a `pager="off"` option which will simply display the HTML (text) output rather than rendering it in the viewer pane in RStudio. It may be a useful start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the diffFile method ...

```
# Load package
library(diffobj)

# Define strings
first_string <- ("It's
a
nice
day")

second_string <- ("it's
a
nice
day")

# Write them out to temporary locations.
first_string_output <- file.path(tempdir(), "first_string_output")
second_string_output <- file.path(tempdir(), "second_string_output")

write.table(first_string, file = first_string_output, col.names = F, row.names = F, quote = F)
write.table(second_string, file = second_string_output, col.names = F, row.names = F, quote = F)

# DiffFile them
diffFile(first_string_output, second_string_output)
```